How do i get chromic abberration on JUST shadows like in this reference image?

Link of the artwork: https://www.behance.net/gallery/123782593/Teddy-bear-Mini-Movie
To clarify I'm aware that there is lens distortion in the whole image but what I'm specifically asking is how did this artist manage to also get distortion on JUST the shadows (as marked by the arrows) without it affecting the objects around it?
I tried using a shadow catcher with an alpha over, so that I could just force it together in Photoshop, but I can only manage to get the render pass in only black and white.

Then I thought maybe I could do something with direct diffuse render pass, but I don't know how to composite the distorted shadows render pass into the final render.

